# How to break .all().each() loop in Protractor once expected element is found?

Tags: protractor

I have list of values present in table (one column table). I want to check whether *XXX* value is present in this table. 
For e.g., list of values are as below:

*ABC*

*PQR*

*XXX*

*XYZ*

*LMN*

I am able to do this using `.all().each()` loop in Protractor as below:

```
element.all(by.className('table_values')).each(function(value){
    console.log(value)
    if(value == 'XXX'){
        console.log('Element found')
    }
});
```

Based on above code snippet, I have 2 questions:

1. Even after *XXX* is found at Position 3, it iterates over remaining 2 values. How can I stop the loop as soon as value is found? I tried using **break** statement, but it gave me **Illegal break statement** error.
2. How can I return *false* if *XXX* is not present?

Answer (score 0):

Array.some should help you. It checks atleast one satisfies the condition.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

It returns if false no element meets the condition.